# How do I persist a many-to-many relationship using Hibernate with @WhereJoinTable?

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I have a many-to-many relationship between Course and User defined by a Role as follows:

Users are associated with a Course based on one of three roles:

- Student (1)
- Marker (2)
- Instructor (3)

In my data model, I have a `User` table and a `Course` table, and a `USERS_COURSES` table. `USERS_COURSES` is a standard many-to-many join table with an extra column that maps to the above enumerated values via an integer.

In my hibernate entity `Course`, I have a method `getStudents()` that is defined as a `@ManyToMany` with a `@WhereJoinTable(clause = "ROLE = 1")`. I can get a set of students just fine this way, but if I want to add a student to a given course, I cannot simply add a new user to this set and persist my `Course` object, because the role column does not have a default value.

Is there a way I can specify a value for the role column when I persist this set?

Here's my get/set methods for reference:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "USERS_COURSES",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "COURSE_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")})
@WhereJoinTable(clause = "ROLE = 1")
@SortComparator(User.FullNameComparator.class)
public SortedSet<User> getStudents() {
    return students;
}

public void setStudents(SortedSet<User> students) {
    this.students = students;
}
```

Here is what I'm attempting to do as a test, but it's failing:

```
Course course = getCourse(1);
User user = UserDAO.getUser(2);
course.getStudents().add(user);
modifyCourse(course);
```

`modifyCourse` is defined as follows:

```
Transaction transaction = null;
try (Session session = HibernateUtil.getSession()) {
    transaction = session.beginTransaction();
    session.saveOrUpdate(course);
    transaction.commit();
    return course;
} catch (HibernateException e) {
    LOG.error(e.getMessage(), e);
    if (transaction != null) {
        transaction.rollback();
    }
    return null;
}
```

This is the error I'm getting:

```
2016-03-23 14:43:04,894 [main] WARN  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 1364, SQLState: HY000
2016-03-23 14:43:04,924 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Field 'ROLE' doesn't have a default value
2016-03-23 14:43:04,928 [main] ERROR org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl - HHH000346: Error during managed flush [could not execute statement]
2016-03-23 14:43:04,972 [main] ERROR com.abopu.codedrop.db.dao.CourseDAO - could not execute statement
```

java.sql.SQLException: Field 'ROLE' doesn't have a default value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`@SQLInsert`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.1/javadocs/org/hibernate/annotations/SQLInsert.html) to specify a custom sql insert statement for the association table:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "USERS_COURSES",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "COURSE_ID")},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")})
@WhereJoinTable(clause = "ROLE = 1")
@SQLInsert(sql = "insert into USERS_COURSES (COURSE_ID, USER_ID, ROLE) values (?, ?, 1)")
@SortComparator(User.FullNameComparator.class)
public SortedSet<User> getStudents() {
    return students;
}
```

[This](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/querysql-cud.html) and [this](https://raymondhlee.wordpress.com/2012/01/07/using-sqlinsert-to-insert-entity-in-hibernate-with-custom-sql/) articles can also be helpful.